# real time gifted chat without socket.io?

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

My react Native 0.66 app uses gifted chat and socket.io to allow users to join a room (created by socket.io) and chat with others in the same room. The socket.io is used to broadcast a message to everyone in a room in real time. But recently socket.io has some connection issue. Is it possible to implement a real time chat using gifted chat only (with no socket.io)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to only use gifted chat to communicate to other devices, **you need a backend**. A good and pretty well documented **alternative to socket.io is **firebase**.**
 A basic guide: https://medium.com/@phylypo/react-native-simple-chat-with-firebase-and-giftedchat-f7dbdff2883a